# ERROR: 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode

Tags: macos, catalina, xcode

## OBSERVATIONS

I was not expecting the command to return an error:

`/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416040)) returns an error:

> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active
> developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
> line tools instance

`ls -l /usr/bin/xcodebuild` returns:

> -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 May 27 19:37 /usr/bin/xcodebuild

`xcodebuild -version` returns:

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

`gcc --version` returns:

> Configured with:
> --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
> Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62) Target:
> x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

## QUESTIONS

Why is the an error returned in the first observation and what remedies are available?

How can I test (without installing anything to determine if I have the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786)?

I am concerned that [changing the active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529693)

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

will cause problems with brew or other installed apps.  Though it would seem that my active directory and the suggested change is the same.

## UPDATES

```
$ ls -l /Applications/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  admin  128 Jul 26 00:06 Polyspace
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel   96 Apr 23 00:52 Safari.app
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 user  staff   96 Sep 30  2019 Sublime Text.app
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 user  staff   96 May 15 20:06 Transmission.app
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 May 27 19:31 Utilities
$ ls /usr/bin | grep -I Xcode
xcode-select
xcodebuild
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the updates you've made to the question? Also it seems that oyu already found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error/17980786#17980786, why are you concerned about following the advice given there?

Comment: Thanks for the response: I think Xcode was installed when I installed brew.  Based on the updates I think that Xcode.app (superset of Xcode?) is not installed.   My concern is that I do not want  'break' whatever has been done with brew.  Hopefully, my concerns are not warranted.

Comment: `Xcode.app` *is* Xcode, the same as `Safari.app` *is* Safari.

Comment: I installed Xcode from the App Store and executed the prescribed `xcode-select`command.  Xcode version is now returned

Answer (score 23):

Assuming your Xcode.app is installed in `/Applications` you can just run

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the an error returned in the first observation

Because `xcodebuild` executable in `/usr/bin` is not useful without Xcode app.

> I am concerned that changing the active directory...
> will cause problems with brew or other installed apps.

No it does not. When Xcode is installed, setting the `xcode-select` path to Xcode app gives you more features: in particular `xcodebuild` which is required for making Xcode projects from `cmake` etc.

> The Command Line Tools package installs the macOS system headers
> inside the macOS SDK. Software that compiles with the installed tools
> will search for headers within the macOS SDK provided by either Xcode
> at:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
>
> or the Command Line Tools at:
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
>
> depending on which
> is selected using xcode-select. The command line tools will search the
> SDK for system headers by default.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-10-release-notes

So there will not be any problem as long as the tool you're concerned about works with SDK, and is not dependent on unix-like `/usr/include` paths.

> Though it would seem that my active directory and the suggested change is the same.

Whenever in doubt, print it:

```
xcode-select --print-path
xcode-select -p
```

Read the man page: `man xcode-select` for more.