# Is installing Xcode necessary?

Tags: xcode, storage

I installed Xcode 12.2 on my MBP. I installed it from App Store and it's 28 gb, while my Mac only has a SSD of 128gb.

I use vscode for all my c/c++ programs so is there a need for me to keep Xcode on my device?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/397221/error-xcodebuild-requires-xcode/397225#397225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C/++ you only need the compiler (clang)/toolchain, which can be installed via commandline:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

### No

You'd need to install Xcode only if you wish to build native apps for macOS, iOS/iPadOS, watchOS or tvOS.

Compiling/Building C/C++ programs does not require you to have a full Xcode installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download and install](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) the [Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339) to save space. These tools are enough to compile your project to an executable binary:

> ### What is the Command Line Tools Package?
>
> The Command Line Tools Package is a small self-contained package available for download separately from Xcode and that allows you to do command line development in macOS. It consists of the macOS SDK and command-line tools such as Clang, which are installed in the /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools directory.

You can remove the Xcode application and run the Terminal command:

```
 xcode-select --install
```